# Remove key and value from nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary like this:

```
book={20:{'start':'2008','reason':'sold'},
      21:{'start':'2009','reason':'returned'},
      22:{'start':'2010','reason':'returned'}}
```

I want to remove items that 'reason'== 'sold' .

The output should be like this:

```
book={21:{'start':'2009','reason':'returned'},
      22:{'start':'2010','reason':'returned'}}
```

This is my code which is not working:

```
for k, v in book:
   if v == 'sold':
       del book[k]
```

Comment: 1. What does happen? 2. Try printing "book[k]" instead of attempting to delete it. What gets printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the job done with some debug stuff.

```
booko = book.copy()
for k in book:
   print('k', k)
   if 'reason' in book[k] and book[k]['reason'] == 'sold':
       print(book[k]['reason'])
       del booko[k]
print booko
book=booko
```

Copied the original because otherwise the iterator doesn't know what's next...

The `dictionary comprehension` is cool, but super weird to grok. I like loops for maintainability. Also as you're learning, you can execute the print statements to see what's actually going on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this error: 'KeyError: 'reason'' .   @Jonathan

Comment: try it now. seems you don't have the 'reason' key in all the dicts.

Comment: Perfect! Yes, I don't have 'reason' in all the dicts. I didn't notice that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
book={20:{'start':'2008','reason':'sold'},
  21:{'start':'2009','reason':'returned'},
  22:{'start':'2010','reason':'returned'}}
new_book = {a:b for a, b in book.items() if b['reason'] != 'sold'}
```

Output:

```
{21: {'start': '2009', 'reason': 'returned'}, 22: {'start': '2010', 'reason': 'returned'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
dictionary = {}
book={20:{'start':'2008','reason':'sold'},
      21:{'start':'2009','reason':'returned'},
      22:{'start':'2010','reason':'returned'}}
for d in book:
   if book[d]['reason'] != 'sold':
      dictionary[d] = book[d]
   else:
      pass
print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{21: {'start': '2009', 'reason': 'returned'}, 22: {'start': '2010', 'reason': 'returned'}}
```

I iterate trough the book dictionary and then i check if `'reason'` column of the dictionary is `'sold'` or not, if it is, pass, if it's not add it to the new dictionary